# how dynamically add treeview into  the combobox

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, treeview

How I can dynamically add treeview into the combobox in wpf..
thakx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with click event handler as given

```
  <TreeView Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"  MouseClick="treeview_MouseClick" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" x:Name="Tree">
```

with Click event you can get the ComboBox

```
private void treeview_MouseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TreeView treeview = sender as TreeView;
        if(treeview == null)
            return;
        var combobox = treeview .Tag as ComboBox;
        combobox .SelectedItem = treeview .SelectedItem;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: this good but still I getting error ..

TreeView.Tag as Combobx it will give me null value..
but when i take the value as treeview and assing into the combobox
it's working, but I am not able to assing this statement...

        combobox .SelectedItem = treeview .SelectedItem;